# ec2 centos userdata not ran

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, aws-cloudformation, ec2-ami

I am trying to deploy an ruby on rails app through centos ec2 instance by using userdata at instance startup, the specify image is an centos 7 image. below is my userdata section. However, the userdata is not working and even the log file was not created when I piped each command output to an log. Does anyone have any insight on this or how to troubleshoot ec2 userdata? I have looked at the cloud-init.log file in /var/logs too but unable to make out which command actually ran and which one did not, I have included the last few lines from the log below as well. any help is appreciated thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y | tee -a log.txt
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo usermod -a -G rvm `whoami` | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
if sudo grep -q secure_path /etc/sudoers; then sudo sh -c "echo export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 >> /etc/profile.d/rvm_secure_path.sh" && echo Environment variable installed; fi | & tee -a log.txt
sudo su ec2-user
rvm install ruby | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
rvm --default use ruby | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash - | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum install -y nodejs | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum -y install ImageMagick-devel | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum -y upgrade | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum -y install git | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk | tee -a log.txt
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk" | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
rails new app-name -m https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectblacklight/spotlight/master/template.rb | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
cd app-name
rake db:migrate | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
solr_wrapper | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
rails server | tee -a /home/ec2-user/log.txt
```

the cloud-init.log

```
2018-12-10 16:24:43,554 - util.py[DEBUG]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 finished at Mon, 10 Dec 2018 21:24:43 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 735.81 seconds
2018-12-10 16:24:43,554 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [420] 52 bytes
2018-12-10 16:24:43,555 - util.py[DEBUG]: Restoring selinux mode for /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-0b323a8331354129b/boot-finished (recursive=False)
2018-12-10 16:24:43,555 - util.py[DEBUG]: Restoring selinux mode for /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-0b323a8331354129b/boot-finished (recursive=False)
2018-12-10 16:24:43,556 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: modules-final/config-final-message: SUCCESS: config-final-message ran successfully
2018-12-10 16:24:43,556 - main.py[DEBUG]: Ran 9 modules with 1 failures
2018-12-10 16:24:43,565 - util.py[DEBUG]: Creating symbolic link from '/run/cloud-init/result.json' => '../../var/lib/cloud/data/result.json'
2018-12-10 16:24:43,566 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
2018-12-10 16:24:43,566 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 14 bytes from /proc/uptime
2018-12-10 16:24:43,566 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'modules' took 687.571 seconds (687.57)
2018-12-10 16:24:43,566 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: modules-final: FAIL: running modules for final
```

Comment: It is better to create a docker image, host it on hub and run the docker container using user data.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation? Did you remember to Base64 encode the userdata?

```
  EventCollectionLc:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Properties:
      UserData: !Base64 
        'Fn::Sub': |
          #!/bin/bash
```